# hector_gazebo stack error when rosmake

Tags: gazebo, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to build hector_quadrotor stack, but it need hector_gazebo first. When I try to build hector_gazebo i get:

/home/franco/ros_workspace/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_thermal_camera/include/hector_gazebo_thermal_camera/gazebo_ros_thermal_camera.h:63:27: error fatal: gazebo/Param.hh: No such file or directory

I think it's a API problem with the new gazebo. Am I in correct?
I am usin Ubuntu 12.04, ROS fuerte, and I have installed (before ROS) Gazebo 1.0.1.

Can help me?

Thanks.
Franco

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37222/hector_gazebo-stack-error-when-rosmake/) by [FrancoR](https://answers.ros.org/users/2595/francor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-06-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2012-06-25**:
Looks like it is an API issue.  In the hector quadroto announcement they did say that they would be updating for Gazebo 1.0 after Fuerte was released: http://www.ros.org/news/2012/03/announcement-of-hector-quadrotor-stack.html.  There is also a Fuerte branch in their svn repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I had the same error, but by browsing in the tu-darmstadt repository i found the branch for fuerte, as JonW said. It compiles without problem.

the source is

http://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/branches/fuerte/hector_gazebo/

they also have all the other packages there.

regards.

Mario

---

Originally posted by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) with karma: 802 on 2012-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1